# Is there any way to post my Java progarms on WordPress blogs?

Tags: java, wordpress, java-web-start

so I have this chess program written in Java. I am trying to post it on my WordPress website so that people can go there and play chess against AI. I have the full code for the chess app. But here are two problems.

1) Java applet is deprecated in modern browsers so I cannot use Java applet.

2) Java-Web-Start is also deprecated on late versions of Java. so I cannot use Java-Web-Start either.

so.... is there any way for me to post my Java chess program on my WordPress webpage?

Comment: Provide the JAR as a download to run locally. Otherwise, no.

Comment: oh... I see. It is so weird and frustrating that it was possible in the past and now it's impossible... feels like technology went backward on this one.

Comment: It was a security vulnerability. It's better that it's gone. There are better ways to do the same things now; client-side technologies are much better. A shame for you, but overall the web is much better for it.

Comment: You can check if converting it to something that can be handled with [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) is possible. If not then you probably need to rewrite it.